# How do I get property values for the parent element of a clicked element using Custom Code in Adobe Launch?

Tags: jquery, adobe-launch

I would like to use the custom code of Data Elements in Adobe Launch to get a text value for the parent element of the clicked element.

I used *$(this).parents('h3').text()* method, but when I checked with debug tool, the text value is not collected properly.
[Custom Code of Data Elements in Adobe Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msx5Y.png)

However, when I check with the console within the page, I can see that the text value exists through that method.

Does Adobe Launch not support that method? 
So how do I get a property value for the parent or child element of a clicked element?

Comment: have you tried native javascript? try `return this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Neither the event nor the element object is internally passed to Data Elements (DE). If you want to be able to reference this stuff in a DE, then you can have the DE return a function, so you can call it like a function and pass it as an argument.

**Example:**

**Data Element Name:** getClickedElementText

**Custom Code:**

```
return function(ev) {
   var ev = ev || {};
   var elem = ev.target || {}:
   return $(elem).parents('h3').text();
}
```

Then in your Rule, in a custom code box (e.g. in a condition, or in an action custom code box, *not* flagged for global scope), you can do this:

```
var text = _satellite.getVar('getClickedElementText')(event);
```

Note that since this DE is returning a function, you cannot reference it in a built-in text field in your rule.

If you want to be able to use `%dataelement%` in UI text fields, then you have to instead put the code in a code box within the rule box (again, *not* globally scoped) to set an adhoc DE.  For example, in a rule condition custom code box:

```
var elem = event.target;
var text = $(elem).parents('h3').text();
_satellite.setVar('clickedElementText',text);
```

And then you can use the `%clickedElementText%` syntax in the UI text fields. Note though that since you are creating an adhoc DE on-the-fly like this, it won't show up in the dropdown search hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for this in Launch's custom code where your Rule is an EBR(Event-Based Rule) as below

```
this.parentNode.innerText
```

Or

```
event.element.parentNode.innerText
```